# File object not working in Java Web App

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, file-io

I have a simple java class in my web application in which i have written the below code but its not working

```
File test= new File("/templates/xmdForModel.xsd");
```

templates folder is inside the root folder of the application.

the location of the file is ----> `application-root/package/test.java`
location of the file is --------> `application-root/testRoot/template/xmdForModel.xsd`

Error

Failed to read schema document 'file:/templates/xmdForModel.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .

Comment: stop there at a breakpoint and evaulate test.getCanonicalPath() to see where your file leads, then correct it

Comment: I think your are missing `testRoot/` in `File("/templates/xmdForModel.xsd");`

Comment: What "is not working"?  Can we see some code or an error message or...something?

Comment: Why are there .java source code files deployed to the web server?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to look up the file name for files inside of your web application, you can use [ServletContext#getRealPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29).

However, I would recommend loading your resources using the classloader with [Class#getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29). This way, it even works if the file does not really exist as a file (for example only inside of a jar).

If this is a file that a user is supposed to edit (or that you write to), I would place it outside of the web application, and then specify an absolute path (for example "/etc/myapp/conf/xmd.xsd") with a configurable prefix.

Comment: you should carefully use this two function. Because the return value is base on which web container you use

Comment: @evilYoung: But isn't that what you want?

Comment: :Sometimes not. For example, when you use Resin as the web container, the return value is related to the value of compiling-loader you set in resin.conf, not the really file path

Answer (score 0):

Path in the File constructor can be absolute or relative. When you start the path with '/' (in a linux based os), it is going to consider that path as an absolute path and create a file/folder in the root of your file structure (not in the root of the project). It will be like specifying c:\templates in windows machine.

Try removing the first slash and running your program. Removing first slash will make the part relative from your .java file. So you can use ../ to switch to parent folder.
java:  application-root/package/test.java 
file: application-root/testRoot/template/xmdForModel.xsd

So from your java file you will need to change directory to application root folder and then select template folder. Like following.

File x = new File("../testRoot/template/xmdForModel.xsd");

---

src:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/path.html

> /home/sally/statusReport is an absolute path. All of the information
>   needed to locate the file is contained in the path string.
>
> A relative path needs to be combined with another path in order to
>   access a file. For example, joe/foo is a relative path. Without more
>   information, a program cannot reliably locate the joe/foo directory in
>   the file system.